# can not open web page in firefox through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to web driver and trying to do some simple automation. I simply want to launch a browser and open a web page with selenium webdriver. I did the eclipse-selenium set up and Firefox gets launched but it doesn't open the web page that I am specifying. I am getting some weird error. I browsed for the solution and tried out many suggestions I found.

Here is the code that I am trying to execute:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class orderingpizza {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

The error which I am getting is:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

I'm using Selenium java 2.42.2, FF 29. What is the issue of this?

Comment: Try to upgrade Firefox to 31

Comment: What version are you using of sel & firefox?

Comment: When I had similar error with WebDriver and Chrome. I had to reinstall Chrome and then it started working.

Comment: I tried with firefox 31 but it is still there

Comment: I am using selenium 2.42.2 and FF 31

Comment: Update your selenium version please..

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the Firefox version and Selenium. Also upgrade your geckodriver.exe

Use single forward slash "/" or double backward "\" in path. Try this code it is working fine on Firefox version 49.0 and Selenium 3.4.0 jars

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:/software and tools/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.quora.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the versioning issue. try upgrading firefox and selenium to a compatible versions